# Checking if Xcopy works properly

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy

I'm working on an issue we have right now with one Batch-File.

The background:

We have an application, where user can create files (CSV,JPG & PDF) and send them to our SAP Server, where the SAP User can work with.

All incoming files created by the App are going to our DMZ-Server, where an Xcopy-Batch is cutting them out to the next Server for ongoing process etc.

Sometimes it appears, that the Batch files cut the files out from the path on our DMZ to send them to the SAP, but they never appears. So that they are not anymore on the DMZ and also not in our SAP Server.

I have the code embedded:

```
@for /f %%a in ('dir /oD /b \\IP-Source-Address\SAP_Datentransfer\EDI\SendData\*.csv^|findstr /i /l "KHS_KS_"') do @set ks_datei=%%a

@for /f %%a in ('dir /oD /b \\IP-Source-Address\SAP_Datentransfer\EDI\SendData\*.csv^|findstr /i /l "KHS_LS_"') do @set ls_datei=%%a

@for /f %%a in ('dir /oD /b \\IP-Source-Address\SAP_Datentransfer\EDI\SendData\*.csv^|findstr /i /l "KHS_PR_"') do @set pr_datei=%%a

@xcopy /r /y "\\DMZ\CarLoS_App\RcvData\Username\*.csv" "\\IP-Destination-Address\SAP_Datentransfer\RcvData\Username">>C:\CarLosApp\LOG\Username.log
@xcopy /r /y "\\DMZ\CarLoS_App\RcvData\Username\*.pdf" "\\IP-Destination-Address\SAP_Scans\PIC-DE">>C:\LOG\Username.log
@xcopy /r /y "\\DMZ\CarLoS_App\RcvData\Username\*.jpg" "\\IP-Destination-Address\SAP_Scans\PIC-DE">>C:\LOG\Username.log


del /F/S/Q  \\DMZ\CarLoS_App\RcvData\Username\.>>C:\CarLosApp\LOG\Username.log
```

I hope I explained the process good enough for a basic understanding. My question: How could I check the script, that the transfer from DMZ to SAP works, before the files get deleted on the DMZ?

Thank you for your Support in advance!

Best Regards,
Legio

Answer (score 0):

Use ROBOCOPY to move the files (copy and delete) in one step. I used line continuation to make the code a bit easier to read.

```
@robocopy "\\DMZ\CarLoS_App\RcvData\Username" ^
          "\\IP-Destination-Address\SAP_Datentransfer\RcvData\Username" ^
          *.csv /mov /is /it /njh /njs /ndl /ns /nc /np /nc >>C:\CarLosApp\LOG\Username.log

@robocopy "\\DMZ\CarLoS_App\RcvData\Username" ^
          "\\IP-Destination-Address\SAP_Scans\PIC-DE" ^
          *.pdf *.jpg /mov /is /it /njh /njs /ndl /ns /nc /np /nc >>C:\LOG\Username.log
```

The MOVE command is not a good choice because it does not support UNC paths for the target, and it will not overwrite a read only file.